# Mocked interface gets two phantom invocations on each property

Tags: c#, moq, xunit, autofixture, automoq

I have a simple class that writes a message to the Console prefixed with the current time. It has a dependency on an `IDateTimeProvider` interface as an abstraction over `DateTime.Now`

```
public interface IDateTimeProvider
{
    DateTime Now { get; }
    DateTime UtcNow { get; }
}

public class MessageWriter
{
    private readonly IDateTimeProvider _dateTimeProvider;

    public MessageWriter(IDateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider)
    {
        _dateTimeProvider = dateTimeProvider;
    }

    public void Write(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{_dateTimeProvider.Now.ToShortTimeString()} : {message}");
    }
}
```

In order to test that the `Write` method calls `IDateTimeProvider.Now` I've written the following test using xUnit, AutoFixture and Moq:

```
public class MessageWriterTests
{
    [Theory, AutoMoqData]
    public void Write_Always_CallsDateTimeProvider(
        [Frozen] Mock<IDateTimeProvider> dateTimeProviderMock,
        MessageWriter sut,
        string message)
    {
        sut.Write(message);

        dateTimeProviderMock.Verify(m => m.Now, Times.Once());
    }
}
```

I'm using `AutoMoqDataAttribute` as seen on http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheorieswithAutoFixture/

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture()
            .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```

The test above fails with the following message:

> Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 3 times: m => m.Now
>
> No setups configured.

```
Performed invocations:
IDateTimeProvider.Now
IDateTimeProvider.UtcNow
IDateTimeProvider.Now
IDateTimeProvider.UtcNow
IDateTimeProvider.Now
   at Moq.Mock.ThrowVerifyException(MethodCall expected, IEnumerable`1 setups,  IEnumerable`1 actualCalls, Expression expression, Times times, Int32 callCount)
   at Moq.Mock.VerifyCalls(Interceptor targetInterceptor, MethodCall expected, Expression expression, Times times)
   at Moq.Mock.VerifyGet[T,TProperty](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression, Times times, String failMessage)
   at Moq.Mock.Verify[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression, Times times, String failMessage)
   at Moq.Mock`1.Verify[TResult](Expression`1 expression, Times times)
   at MoqBug.Tests.MessageWriterTests.Write_Always_CallsDateTimeProvider(Mock`1 dateTimeProviderMock, MessageWriter sut, String message) in c:\Users\rik van der sanden\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MoqBug\MoqBug.Tests\MessageWriterTests.cs:line 21
```

So my question is: where do the extra invocations (two for each property on the interface) come from?

If I forego using the `AutoMoqDataAttribute` the problem goes away:

```
    [Theory, AutoData]
    public void Write_Always_CallsDateTimeProvider(
        string message)
    {
        IFixture fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
        Mock<IDateTimeProvider> dateTimeProviderMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IDateTimeProvider>>();
        MessageWriter sut = fixture.Create<MessageWriter>();

        sut.Write(message);

        dateTimeProviderMock.Verify(m => m.Now, Times.Once());
    }
```

This version of the test passes, but I'd rather do it using the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using version 4.1.1308.2120 of `Moq`, that one that's currently the lowest version required by `AutoFixture.AutoMoq` and hence the version that got installed by Nuget.

Updating `Moq` to the latest version (4.5.28 in this particular case) fixed the problem.